# MVC Problems setting the selected item of the dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

In my controller I set the SelectedYear field as follows;

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Administrator, AdminAccounts")]
public ActionResult BankHoliday(int? id)
{
    BankHolidayViewModel BankHolidayViewModel = new BankHolidayViewModel();

    int year = DateTime.Now.Year;
    if (id.HasValue)
       year = id.GetValueOrDefault();

    BankHolidayViewModel.SelectedYear = year;
    BankHolidayViewModel.GetYearData(year);
    return View(BankHolidayViewModel);
}
```

Whenever I step through the code, the SelectedYear value is always correct on the return statement. In the Year DropDownList below, this is the Value field that sets the selected item in the DropDownList;

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/AdminAccounts.master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.WebUI.Models.BankHolidayViewModel>" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="TitleContent" runat="server">
    BankHoliday
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="AdminAccountsContent" runat="server">
        <h3>Bank Holiday Administration</h3>
        <p>Select the year: <%: Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedYear, Model.YearList)%></p>
       <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                $("#SelectedYear").change(function () {
                    var year = $("#SelectedYear").val();
                    $("#wholepage").load("/AdminAccounts/BankHoliday/" + year);
                });
            });
```

### *** EDIT: ADDED INFO ***

The YearList is defined as follows;

```
public class BankHolidayViewModel
{
    public IList<BankHolidayExtended> BankHolidays { get; set; }
    public IList<BankHolidayYear> Years { get; set; }
    public int SelectedYear = DateTime.Now.Year;
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearList
    {
        get
        {
            return this.Years.Select(item => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = item.Year.ToString(),
                Value = item.Year.ToString()
            });
        }
    }
```

### *** END EDIT ***

For some reason when the View is rendered, there is no selected item in the dropdownlist. How do I fix this?

Comment: How are you declaring and setting your YearList?

Comment: I have put in the extra info. SO may need to format it to make it easier to read.

Comment: Highlight the code and Ctrl-K or press the button with binary to format it.  You can also prepend and append it with a `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't really want to change my object to a SelectList, although I am sure that would have worked.
Instead I got the answer by changing the getter;

```
public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> YearList
{
    get
    {
        return this.Years.Select(item => new SelectListItem
        {
            Text = item.Year.ToString(),
            Value = item.Year.ToString(),
            Selected = item.Year == this.SelectedYear
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your "Inherits" needs to inherit your ViewModel.

```
Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<ViewModels.BankHolidayViewModel>"
```

When you create the YearList, you also need to set the selected value.  Something like

```
 YearList = new SelectList(GetYears(), "year", "year", SelectedYear);
```

*EDIT*
In your view you can set the selected value:

```
<%= Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedYear, new SelectList(Model.YearList, "Value", "Text", Model.SelectedYear))%>
```

Or you can do it when you originally set up the Year List as I put above.  GetYears() would return the years for the list.

```
public SelectList YearList { get; private set; }
public class BankHolidayViewModel(int year)
{
    YearList = new SelectList(GetYears(), "Value", "Text", year);
```

Then when you return the view

```
return View(new BankHolidayViewModel(year));
```

Comment: It does, but somehow this got truncated when this got published. So my inherits clause looks like; Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<SHP.WebUI.Models.BankHolidayViewModel>"